# Should I use exceptions to solve bad user input?

Tags: python, exception

I always learned, that exceptions should only be thrown in real exceptional cases and not be used for expectable error cases. But in [Exception Handling](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Exception_Handling) tutorial I found this example:

```
def do_stuff_with_number(n):
          print(n)

  the_list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

  for i in range(20):
      try:
          do_stuff_with_number(the_list[i])
      except IndexError: # Raised when accessing a non-existing index of a list
          do_stuff_with_number(0)
```

Here is an exception used to validate and solve a user input error. Isn't that a very bad example for exceptions? Or are there cases in which it is good to use it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are a great way to go in most errors as they are mostly used to immediately terminate the program. In regards to user input, it might just be easier to re-ask the user for another input.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are a good way to handle the unexpected. While this form is fine, in a production setting, it is a good idea to deal more explicitly with the most common exceptions

Answer (score 0):

It's not "a very bad" example. Exception are meant to raise the attention on something that should not occur, such as accessing a non-existent value.

The only thing that I could argue is the way the exception is handled. Why call the same function but with a `0` default parameter? What if `the_list` itself (side note: it's a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), not a list!) contains `0`? And what if the element exists but is unexpected?

As a general role, do not let the program fail for you: if you know in a particular point that something is not ok, throw an error! The caller should always catch that error and deal with it doing something useful. Finally, be aware that the `try` is inside a `for` loop, meaning that you don't care if some tuple value (or all) could not be processed by `do_stuff_with_number()` function. A situation like this in my opinion could be handled with `if`s while looping `the_list`.